# What is the difference between the total cpu usage and cpu usage in processes list?

Tags: ubuntu, cpu-usage, glances

I am new to Glance. And I have a quesiton, what is the difference between the toal cpu usage and cpu usage in processes list?

For example：

[image]

CPU usage of PID 9303 is 100%, but in top left corner, the total cpu usage shows only 3.9%，why?

And would it cause any problem to server if the cpu usage of any process is almost 100% ?

Comment: it is normal for xvnc to reach 100% cpu usage. For your question, I do not know the exact answer, but I believe it shows 100% for a single core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 100% CPU usage is for a single core. You have 32 cores in total. If you add up CPU% of all the processes and divide it by 32 cores, you get a total CPU usage of approx 4% which is exactly what is shown in the top.

Comment: Your suggestion is correct, i find evidence in document:https://glances.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aoa/ps.html  `CPU% : 
% of CPU used by the process

If Irix/Solaris mode is off (‘0’ key), the value is divided by logical core number`